# detect if application running on virtual box

Tags: c++, virtual-machine

I went thrrough [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498371/how-to-detect-if-my-application-is-running-in-a-virtual-machine) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application) in stackoverflow. But code given here doesnt work for virtual box. I have also tried [redpill](http://www.invisiblethings.org/papers/redpill.html) but thats not working too. my application will run on both linux and windows(preferably).
Please let me know if anyone has any solution.

Edit: Preet Sangha's link not working as well

Comment: No. The general purpose of virtualization is to run multiple OSes simultaneously on the same hardware by being "close enough" - not necessarily indistinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

VBox 1.0 uses a different method. Check http://spth.virii.lu/eof2/articles/WarGame/vboxdetect.html

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.gedzac.com/rrlf.dr.eof.eZine/articles/WarGame/vboxdetect.html

Check if the pseudo-device `\\.\VBoxMiniRdrDN` exists in the system (you need `CreateFile`())

```
#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    if(CreateFile("\\\\.\\VBoxMiniRdrDN",GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"VBox detected!","Warning",MB_OK|MB_ICONWARNING);
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Not inside VBox","Info",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this .. but this not working (tried on win xp, vbox3.2)

Comment: have you got the client tools running?