# How to detect if the script is running on a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, perl, virtualization, detection

I don't think the question needs any explanation.
I'm writing a software that can boot virtual machines to simulate a network. I would like to disable this feature if the software is already running on a virtual machine.

I already read this post: [How to detect if my application is running in a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498371/how-to-detect-if-my-application-is-running-in-a-virtual-machine)
But I need to do it on Linux and that post covers only Windows.

I'm tagging it as a `Perl` question as I've to do it in Perl, but probably there are some file in `proc` or somewhere else to check and it's the same for all languages. I don't know actually.

I'm interested in detecting mainly VirtualBox and KVM, as those are the VMs I'm using.

So, any suggestion?

Comment: *which* virtual machine software are you using? The instructions probably differ for different VMs.

Comment: Why do you ask? An ideal VM should not be detectable, since by definition it should behave like a real machine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I will talk specific to VMware and virtual Box Virtual Machines running Linux as guest Operating system.
If you run below command, you will come to know that the underlying hardware is VMware/VirtualBox which certifies that it is a Virtual Machine.

For VMware guest:

```
# dmidecode  | grep -i product
        Product Name: VMware Virtual Platform
```

For Virtual Box guest:

```
# dmidecode  | grep -i product
    Product Name: VirtualBox
```

"`dmidecode`" is a linux system command. You can have perl run `dmidecode` in the beginning of your script and extract the value. If it is a virtual machine then the script should exit without any further execution.

I do not have any other hypervisor at my disposal to get you what above command return on them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google yields [dmo.ca/ blog/ How to detect virtualization](http://www.dmo.ca/blog/detecting-virtualization-on-linux/)

Perl module and everything.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Sys::Detect::Virtualization](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Sys-Detect-Virtualization/), available on CPAN?

Answer (score 0):

On a modern Linux system with systemd installed, you can simply run [systemd-detect-virt](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-detect-virt.html). If it detects it is running in a virtual environment (both VMs **and** containers) it will print a string indicating the detected environment and exit with 0, otherwise, it will print "none" and exit with a non-zero value.
In PERL you could do something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
if ( system("systemd-detect-virt >& /dev/null") == 0){
    print "Running in a virtual machine\n";
}
else {
    print "No virtualization technologies detected\n";
}
```