# VB6 or VBScript code to detect if running on VMware or Virtual Machines?

Tags: vbscript, vb6, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

Is there VB6 or VBScript code to detect if running on VMware or Virtual Machines?

The following links show the codes on other programming languages. Is there a way on VB6 or VBScript?

[Detect virtualized OS from an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application)

[How to detect if my application is running in a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498371/how-to-detect-if-my-application-is-running-in-a-virtual-machine)

[Detect if your program is running inside a Virtual Machine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9823/Detect-if-your-program-is-running-inside-a-Virtual)

Answer (score 2):

Vmware have [this article](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009458) about different approaches:

> Virtual BIOS DMI information
>   The VMware virtual BIOS has many VMware-specific identifiers which programs can use to detect hypervisors. For the DMI string check, use the BIOS serial number and check for either string "VMware-" or "VMW" (for Mac OS X guests running on Fusion).

Here's a script for accessing the bios serial number:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?572678-RESOLVED-Getting-CPU-ID-and-BIOS-ID

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed working on Microsoft and VMware.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

For Each objItem in colItems
  strModel = objItem.Model
    If InStr(UCase(strModel), "VIRTUAL") Then
      WScript.Echo "VM"
    End If
Next
```