# Detect running on virtual machine

Tags: swift, macos

Is it possible to detect if my MacOS app is running on a virtual machine?
(I don't mean the simulator, just some VM like VirtualBox or anything else..)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498371/how-to-detect-if-my-application-is-running-in-a-virtual-machine and multiple others.

Answer (score 2):

I only have VMWare but the techniques I used can be extended to VirtualBox. Besides below simple techniques, each VM vendor has an interface to talk to host system. However they may require higher privileges.

## VMware

1. VMWare Tools
   If VMWare Tools is installed, you may check following files.

**GFX card**

You can check whether VmTools is installed. Particulary the presence of `VMwareGfx.kext` inside `/Library/Extensions` folder

**VMware Tools Daemon Launcher**

`/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vmware.launchd.vmware-tools-userd`

**VMware Tools Daemon**

`/Library/Application Support/VMware Tools/vmware-tools-daemon`

You can also check if there is VMware Graphics card present by checking `IORegistry`
Since VMware GFX has following

Device ID:    0x0405
  Revision ID:  0x0000
  Vendor ID:    0x15ad

2. Model Identifier
   You can get all information about device with `system_profiler`

For example `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` gives following information

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name: Apple device
  Model Identifier: VMware7,1
  Processor Speed: 3.23 GHz
  Number of Processors: 2
  Total Number of Cores: 2
  L2 Cache (per Processor): 256 KB
  L3 Cache (per Processor): 6 MB
  Memory: 2 GB
  Boot ROM Version: VMW71.00V.0.B64.1507021939
  SMC Version (system): 2.8f0
  Serial Number (system): VMiZVX4JH1rt
  Hardware UUID: 564D8995-57E0-91F5-AEDF-1968AB31F81E
```

Model Identifier and Boot ROM can be used to find out VMware

`system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Model Identifier/ {print $3}'`

3. Other virtual devices

   - VMware Virtual SATA Hard Drive
   - VMware Virtual USB
   - VMware Virtual SATA CDRW Drive