# vmware keyboard mapping issues

Tags: delphi, vmware, key-bindings

I am trying to develop in Windows (XP) while using VMWare fusion.  I have issues with the keyboard, namely the numpad.

I figure the issue is with the vmware mapping of the keyboard because EVERY software I run in vmware has similar issues, be it a text or spreadsheet.

I looked at the code generated by the onkeydown event and it is way off where it should be. I wonder how I could fix the mapping, if it is fixable by the user, that is? I suspect it is a concordance table that is used and the concordance does not match the proper VK_Key expected by windows. I could create a short 22-key table for my needs but it would be a haystack solution. It might help to know I use VMWare Fusion 2.

While I am on the topic, does anyone know how to have Delphi recognize it is running in a virtual environment? I have not found anything on that topic either.

Comment: "*does anyone know how to have Delphi recognize it is running in a virtual environment?*" - see [How to detect if my application is running in a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498371/)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to update the vmware tools of the VM. It will be ok !

Regards