# Persistent system / processor ID that stays across reinstalls and drive changes (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7

I'm looking to produce a unique ID for some embedded systems I manage. The systems are running Windows Embedded 7 Standard and .NET 4.0. The IDs must:

- Be relatively unique -- each embedded system is running on the same motherboard, drive, etc. and I can't have collisions.
- Persist across reinstalls -- these computers get reimaged with new versions of our software regularly.
- Cannot rely on the disk serial number -- we're not using real disks, but rather CF cards with a CF to SATA adapter, and the CF cards are swapped out occasionally.

Also, I have multiple NICs in the machine, so relying on the on-board NIC MAC address will work only if someone can tell me how to identify which NIC is on-board vs a USB device. After further research it looks like this isn't possible within the scope of managed code.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=VS.85).aspx) to obtain information about the machine's CPU, using the [Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(VS.85).aspx) class. Then you can construct a unique id for the machine from attributes such as `ProcessorId` and `UniqueId`.

This way you would be using each machine's CPU itself as the persisten "store" for the machine id.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101772/win32-processoris-processorid-unique-for-all-computers, the `ProcessorId` isn't unique across all PCs.

Comment: That's why you need to combine it with UniqueId. Basically, ProcessorId gives you the CPU's model or feature set, and UniqueId is unique within a given model or feature set. A combination of both is apparently guaranteed to be unique across machines.

Comment: UniqueId comes back as null on every system I've tested. According to some Googling, it seems to only be implemented on Pentium III.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't work, I think that you shouldn't accept this as an answer. It's only fair.