# Can processor id be used for AES crypto key?

Tags: c#, aes, mac-address

I am using the code below to get processor id:

```
System.Management.ManagementClass theClass = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection theCollectionOfResults = theClass.GetInstances();

foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject currentResult in theCollectionOfResults)
{
    MessageBox.Show(currentResult["ProcessorID"].ToString());
}
```

Is processor ID a unique ID for every computer? I want to generate a random unique number for every computer to use as a AES crypto key. I don't want to use MAC address because i know that MAC address can be changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WIN32_Processor::Is ProcessorId Unique for all computers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101772/win32-processoris-processorid-unique-for-all-computers)

Comment: Additionally: think of what will happen if some hardware component that you base your crypto key on suddenly dies.

Comment: why not just use `Guid.NewGuid()`?  Even this isn't really ideal - but if you're already thinking of using something as easily retrievable as a CPUID you might as well just generate a Guid and store it somewhere; possibly encrypting that with some private key known only to your program.  Even then, though, you have the issue that the program can be decompiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Processor ID is not guaranteed to be unique for every cpu or guaranteed to exist at all.
2. Hardware can be replaced - you can't change that fact.

Suggestions: 
if you need to uniquely identify a machine - it is ok to use the processor Id or MAC address or both for uniqueness. (or any other hardware related number).
but you must keep in mind you id the hardware - not the user, so if the hardware has changed it is much like if someone you know took a face lift and now you don't recognize him.

If you need to identify the user (which I think is better) just let him choose a username and a password.

If you need to make sure that only one previously identified user is using your app, and your'e afraid he will be pirating your app.. the only way is having a server/central point.

Answer (score 0):

It' s bad solution because CPU must support CPUID instructions and system may be contains more one CPU.