# iot-core custom oem image/ffu: crashing only in custom oem/ffu image. Bottom line: looking for a unique board ID

Tags: raspberry-pi, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

We have an iot-core UWP, headless app that runs fine (for months, hundreds of devices) when deployed directly from Visual Studio 2015 or as an App onto the retail iot-core distribution. In order to avoid over-air-update problems caused by recent automatic iot-core updates, we are trying to get a custom oem image/ffu built and deployed to the microsoft store. However, even after walking through the documentation/examples in detail, our app is still crashing when we deploy our oem image/ffu.

**UPDATE**

OK, no debugger still, but I found where it crashes, now is the question why the oem-ffu behaves differently from the side-deployed code (our code is identical) Since iot-core/UWP provices no way to get the board-UUID, I use the MAC of the primary network interface. To get this, I use this http://embedded101.com/BruceEitman/entryid/676/Windows-10-IoT-Core-Getting-the-MAC-Address-from-Raspberry-Pi which requires that a webserver be running, which it normally is, otherwise the console webapp would not work. However, on the OEM-Custom-Build-Version I get a crash in this routine. I don't know where since I can't debug, but it crashes, and I get a null back, which causes my azure storage connect to crash. I do not block processing since I have a retry loop... Anyway, what is the difference or what must we do to enable this code to also work in the OEM build?

**The grass roots issue is**: all I really need is a unique ID for the RPi board from somewhere... which does not seem possible via C#!? See [How to get the processor serial number of Raspberry PI 2 with Windows IOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960375/how-to-get-the-processor-serial-number-of-raspberry-pi-2-with-windows-iot/33979847#33979847)

So it looks like my MAC-Address solution above was the best we can expect at the moment, but doesn't work on the oem build. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to avoid problem with auto update, you can use powershell script or putty to disable auto-update. Will that work for you?

Below is the command line you can use to disable auto-update,

1. Use powershell or putty to connect to pi using administrator
2. `sc.exe config wuauserv start=disabled`
3. `sc.exe query wuauserv`
4. `sc.exe stop wuauserv`
5. `sc.exe query wuauserv`
6. `REG.exe QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv /v Start`

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is one workaround we have considered, but is still a workaround that may bite us back later. More detail now added to my post.

Comment: Jackie, wondering if there is a REG.exe command to enable access to the on-board ethernet's (LAN) MAC or even a reliable entry for this MAC in the REG that we can access?