# how to implement copy protection for installing my .net application

Tags: visual-studio, copy-protection

I have gone through the several samples in the web.I understood to protect software by giving 
Password for each application.I am not asking about abstract concept because I had developed one concept for mine.My question is Where can I implement this codes ?

I read about various options in visual studio such as setup project,clickonce.In setup project I can't add any executables or any script to password protect before installing my application.

I want user to give password during installation so that the installation process proceeds and finished succesfully

How can I achieve this in visual studio ?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want to password protect the installer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET copy protection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142217/net-copy-protection)

Comment: "the program can be installed only when the user enter password"-this is What I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, the only way that I know that you will be able to do this in Visual Studio (your actual question) is to write your own application to be an installer.  Even then the password will probably coded into your installer, so will be easy to hack.  I would recommend you either look into another technology or addin.  Why not copy protect the application and by an off the shelve plug in to do the security?  In this area I really wouldn't re-invent the wheel - it's not worth the effort (and therefore cost)