# Does Windows provide a unique identifier I could use to enforce a free trial?

Tags: windows, trial

Does the Windows operating system contains any unique computer/OS id?

This is for my own software. I want to create 30 day trial/demo version.

Here is what I want to do:

1. When someone installs a trial I grab the unique ID, send it to server.
2. After the 30 day trial, if software is reinstalled, the server blocks the trial version.

So the real question is: Does Windows contains any unique IDs I could rely on?

I think that IP address is not a reliable option.

Comment: At first, I thought you were talking about doing some kind of trial with Windows, but then, I realized you are probably talking about providing a trial version of your software. Your phrasing is misleading.

Comment: Unique ID of what? The computer? The install of Windows? The install of your stuff?

Comment: Yes, unique ID of operating system for my own software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows has a DigitalProductId. You can access its value in registry at the following location:

```
LocalMachine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think widows key isn't enoungh:
Windows 7 Family Pack - 3 licences for different computers at any one time;
or any pirates, etc.

You could use NetworkAdapter's MAC instead. You can get MAC quite easy, here's an example in .NET:
[Read MAC Address from network adapter in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218284/read-mac-address-from-network-adapter-in-net)
Sometimes computer can have 2 interfaces, so you could combine them into one key.