# Read MAC address from network adapter

Tags: .net, networking, compact-framework, mac-address

I need to get the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of a [Windows Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile) device. Is it possible to do this without using, say, OpenNetCF, only by [.NET Compact Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework)? The solution is in C# ([Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008), a smart device project).

Having read *[Read MAC Address from network adapter in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218284/read-mac-address-from-network-adapter-in-net)*, I wanted to use the example by **plinth**, but there was no kernel32.dll on the device.

Is there aother way to get the MAC address in .NET Compact Framework, or how could I replace the following methods:

```
     [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory")]
     private static extern void ByteArray_To_IPAdapterInfo(ref AdapterInfo dst, Byte[] src, int size);
     [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory")]
     private static extern void IntPtr_To_IPAdapterInfo(ref AdapterInfo dst, IntPtr src, int size);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the MAC address, but without using a library like OpenNETCF's SDF then you simply have to do the same thing it does in your own code.  You need to P/Invoke [`GetAdaptersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450394.aspx), something like this:

```
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetAdaptersInfo(byte[] pAdapterInfo, ref uint pOutBufLen);
```

You'll want to call it once with a `null` first parameter to get the size, then allocate a byte array of the proper size and recall it.  It will fill it with an array of [`IP_ADAPTER_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891170.aspx) structs that you then parse for each adapter in the system.  The `Address` member is what you're after for the MAC address.

Comment: But how should I convert the received byte array into array of structs? Or how should I extract each struct from the byte array?

Comment: In the thread, I mentioned earlier in the question, plinth used methods from kernel32.dll (IntPtr_To_IPAdapterInfo, ByteArray_To_IPAdapterInfo). But kernel32.dll is not available on windows mobile (isn't it?).

Comment: I parsed the byte array in the SDF code using unsafe code as it seemed the fastest way.  You could just as easily create a sruct and do member-wise setting of variables.  If all you want is the MAC, you could actually just copy from the resulting array at the proper offset into a local array for the address bytes.

Comment: I don't follow as to why you'd use CopyMemory like you have in your question, even on the desktop.  `Marshal.PtrToStructure` seems to be more appropriate, but the CF marshaler is probably going to fail on a struct this complex.